# Using OR in negative lookahead

Tags: regex, pcre

Given an input like @1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3. I want to capture what is after @2= when @3=B3 and also verify that subsequently, @2= should contain the same value which was captured OR the value should be "ABC"

The patterns that should match are:

`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=B2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3` `@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=B2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=ABC@3=B3`
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=B2@3=C3`

The pattern that should not match `@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=B2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B10@3=B3`
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=B1@2=B10@3=B3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3`

I am able to do the part when it should match the entire string using negative lookaround. But I am not able to the OR part i.e. @2=ABC if the string does not match.

https://regex101.com/r/eCYCtg/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your current regex matches when the repeating @2= has the value starting with the captured value before. You need to add @ in the negative lookahead, `(?!\1@)`.

To fix the pattern as you need you need to add `ABC@` as an alternative to this lookahead: `(?!\1@|ABC@)`. It will now fail the negative lookahead check (and thus will allow the match to occur) if the entire `@2` value is `ABC` or the same value as captured before into Group 1.

You may use

```
^(?:(?!@2=[^@]*@3=B3(?:[@>]|$)).)*@2=([^@]*)@3=B3(?:[@>]|$)(?!.*@2=(?!\1@|ABC@)[^@]*@3=B3(?:[@>]|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X0dSG0/2).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to say that @1=ABC if @2's value does not match?

Comment: @mohit What do you mean? Match even if @2's is not valid, but the second `@1` is `ABC`? I.e. this - `@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=ABC@2=B10@3=B3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3` should match?

Comment: @mohit Add `@1=(?!ABC@)` into the big negative lookahead, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/X0dSG0/4). The regex is too cumbersome, I suggest using something more readable and maintainable.